# Is it possible to group different values from one single column into a one single row in the same column in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

There are 2 columns in a table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | X1 |
| 2 | X2 |
| 3 | Y1 |
| 4 | Y2 |
| 5 | X3 |

Is it possible to count the ids and group the names in new groups like 'Xs' (X1, X2, X3) and 'Ys' (Y1, Y2)? So it will look like this:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | Xs |
| 2 | Ys |

SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table GROUP BY *what?*

I'm using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just group by the first character:

```
select count(*), left(name, 1)
from the_table
group by left(name, 1);
```

If the `id` is not unique you might want:

```
select count(distinct id), left(name, 1)
from the_table
group by left(name, 1);
```

---

Edit after the scope was changed:

If you need some kind of mapping between values, use a `CASE` expression:

```
select count(*), 
       case 
         when name in ('Bananas', 'Apples', 'Oranges') then 'Fruit'
         when name in ('Germany', 'France', 'Austria') then 'Country'
         else 'Something else'
       end
from the_table
group by 2;
```

Comment: Thanks, in this example I used X1, X2, X3, etc. for a simplicity's sake, my bad. But what if the values are completely different like Apples, Bananas, Oranges and I want to group them in Fruits? Is there any way around this?

Comment: @MD: well this answers your original questions. It's usually not appreciated to completely change your question after you have received an answer. See my edit to address this new problem

Comment: @MD . . . I would suggest that you accept one of the answers here and ask a *new* question if you did not ask the right question this time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It gets the string before the first numeric character and groups by that.

```
-- This is auxiliary data for testing purposes
    with aux (id, name) as(
    select 1,   'Apple1' union all
    select 2,   'X2' union all
    select 3,   'Y1' union all
    select 4,   'Apple2'union all
    select 5,   'X3')
-- This is the actual query
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) as id,
        regexp_matches(name, '^[a-zA-Z ]+') as name
    FROM
        aux
    GROUP BY
        2;
```

Output:

```
id  name
--------
2   {X}
1   {Y}
2   {Apple}
```

DB Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=294c87a421a7a83cd5a62d982325dcb7

Comment: Thanks, in this example I used X1, X2, X3, etc. for a simplicity's sake, my bad. But what if the values are completely different like Apples, Bananas, Oranges and I want to group them in Fruits? Is there any way around this?

Comment: @MD there was a bug which I've just fixed. Please test it and let mne know if any issues.